# sum += (i*8); beginner can some one explain the problem I’m getting confused

Tags: c, for-loop

```
sum += (i\*8);
```

Can some one explain the problem? I, as a beginner, I am getting confused.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i == 1; i < 11; i ++)
  {
    sum += (i*8);
  } I
  printf("The value of sum is %d", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

can someone explain

Comment: you don't state a problem so we can't explain a problem.

Comment: `int i == 1` -> `int i = 1`. Next time tell us what problem you have. Read this: [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Instead of write `i == 1`, write `i = 1`. That assigns 1 to the variable `i`.

- `i == 1` : comparison
- `i = 1` : assignment